# Separate search keywords and facets

Tags: java, regex, groovy, split

I have query strings something along those lines:

```
String query = 'metabolism and heart and TAXONOMY:40674 AND curation:"Non curated" GO:GO:34212 and cancer'
```

I am trying to extract from this string query the searching keywords. The expected result for this query is

```
metabolism and heart and cancer
```

How I have been doing?

```
String regex = '[a-z_A-Z0-9]*:\"?.+\"?'
query.replaceAll(regex, '')
```

This snippet works well if the query string is put at the beginning of the query string like below:

```
String query = 'metabolism and heart and cancer and TAXONOMY:40674 AND curation:"Non curated" GO:GO:34212'
```

The facets are couples like `curation:"Non curated"` (i.e., having spaces in the value and wrapped by the double quotes) or `GO:GO:34212` (i.e., having the second colon). Otherwise, they are patterns like `TAXONOMY:234334`.

What I am doing wrong here? Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your regex to cover the alphabetical strings to also account for spaces and re-write your regex as this,

```
[a-z_A-Z0-9]*:(?:"\w+(?: \w+)"\s*|\w+(?: \w+)\s*)?
```

And replace the matched parts with empty string.

The problem with your regex is, this part in your regex `\"?.+\"?` has optional doublequotes due to which `.+` matches greedily everything till the end of string and removes the rest of the string keeping only string before `TAXONOMY:` which is not what you desire.

For correctly addressing the problem you should try matching doublequoted string separately with non-doublequoted string. Also, since your string has space separated words, you need to use `\w+(?: \w+)` part for correctly matching space separated words to match. `\s*` after that consumes extra whitespaces that are not desired and finally matches all your string and replacement with empty string leaves you with the desired string.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cLhFge/1)**

Try this Java code,

```
String s = "metabolism and heart and TAXONOMY:40674 AND curation:\"Non curated\" GO:GO:34212 and cancer";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[a-z_A-Z0-9]*:(?:\"\\w+(?: \\w+)\"\\s*|\\w+(?: \\w+)\\s*)?", ""));
```

Prints,

```
metabolism and heart and cancer
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. I think it answers my question.

Comment: @Tung: I'm glad my answer helped you :)

Comment: If I want to remove logical operations leading facets which I want to replace when the operations present, how can we accomplish? The suggested regex doesn't cope with my expectation exactly. Having a look at the link to Regex Demo, the regex improperly matches.